# Copy field value from one field to another

Tags: javascript, html, input, copy, field

I need to copy two field values from two individual fields to their corresponding fields further on in another form on the same page.

Input field: First Name
Input field: Last Name

Copy these values to:

Input field: Billing First Name
Input Field: Shipping First Name

I have tried the following code to no avail, I hacked it from another website which has a checkbox for the same thing, in my case, there is a form for entering customers first name, last name and email, the customer then clicks the Continue button, and the next form loads, this form is where I would like to auto-full the first/last name as per the initial form.

This is the code I am using between the in the  of the document.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function FillBilling(f) {
  if(f.dispatch[checkout.update_steps].submit == true) {
    f.user_data[firstname].value = f.user_data[b_firstname].value;
    f.user_data[lastname].value = f.user_data[b_lastname].value;
  }
}
</script>
```

The fields are generated as default like this, unfortunately I cannot change the ID nor the name values.

First Name:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[firstname]" id="elm_6">
```

Last Name:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[lastname]" id="elm_7">
```

Continue Button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="dispatch[checkout.update_steps]">
```

Billing First Name:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[b_firstname]" id="elm_14">
```

Billing Last Name:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[s_firstname]" id="elm_16">
```

I think, but may be wrong, that because the Continue submit button has a name containing a dot (dispatch[checkout.update_steps]), this breaks the Javascript, but I'm not sure.

I have also noted that the "First Name", "Last Name" fields and "Continue" button are on a seperate form, the data is sent to the second form on the same page via Ajax. The first form has name="step_one_contact_information_form" and the second form (Billing First Name, Billing Last Name) has name="step_two_billing_address".

Any ideas?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make it with jQuery. It is very simple I have made this for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/FPsdy/1/

Here is an example of the code:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
   $('#elm_14').val($('#elm_6').val());
   $('#elm_16').val($('#elm_7').val());
});
```

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work, because I am an idiot.

There are two seperate forms on the  page...

First form:

<form method="post" action="/" class="cm-ajax cm-ajax-force" name="step_one_contact_information_form">

Second form:

<form method="post" action="/" class="cm-ajax cm-ajax-force cm-ajax-full-render" name="step_two_billing_address">

So it seems I need to find out how to pass the values from one form to the next form, but I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far, it is appreciated alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Add an onclick event to your button (preferably with event listeners, but the following way will also work)

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="dispatch[checkout.update_steps]" onclick="return fillBilling()">
```

and change your function to look do something like this:

```
function fillBilling() {
    document.getElementsByName("user_data[b_firstname]")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("user_data[firstname]")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("user_data[s_firstname]")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("user_data[lastname]")[0].value;
    return false;
}
```

You can use `document.getElementByID("elm_[x]")` instead if the id's will always be the same (replace [x] with their respective IDs)

Also, I recommend changing the button to type "button" so if you're not going to use it to submit the form:

```
<input type="button"... />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work, because I am an idiot.

There are two seperate forms on the  page...

First form:

<form method="post" action="/" class="cm-ajax cm-ajax-force" name="step_one_contact_information_form">

Second form:

<form method="post" action="/" class="cm-ajax cm-ajax-force cm-ajax-full-render" name="step_two_billing_address">

So it seems I need to find out how to pass the values from one form to the next form, but I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far, it is appreciated alot!